Error: File /vercel/path0/api/node_modules/transformers/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/exports.js does not exist
I am having err in deploying site in vercel. My website is running smoothly in localhost but having err in deploying
err:
enter image description here
this is website directory
this is package.json:
enter image description hereenter image description here
Kindly help out of this err ?

Please don't post pictures of code, errors, configuration or other text. Copy the original text to your question.
